# Prove that $\frac{1}{a_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n} = 1$ implies $a_n < 2^{n!}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, induction, contest-math

> Let $a_1, ..., a_n$ be positive integers such that $a_1 \leq \cdots  \leq a_n. $ Prove that $\frac{1}{a_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n} = 1$ implies $a_n < 2^{n!}$.

Perhaps a proof by reverse induction might work? The idea is to show that if $a_n \ge 2^{n!}$, then for all $i, a_i\ge 2^{i!}$. This would result in a contradiction because $\frac{1}{a_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}\leq \frac{1}{2^{1!}} +\cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n!}} < \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}2 = 1.$ If I assume the result holds for $k=n,\cdots , m+1, m < n,$ (i.e. $a_k\ge 2^{k!}$ for $k=n,\cdots , m+1$ ), then I need to show that $a_m \ge 2^{m!}$, or equivalently that $\frac{1}{a_m} \leq \frac{1}{2^{m!}}$. Clearly, $\frac{1}{a_m} \leq \sqrt[m]\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_m}$. And also, $\sqrt[m]\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_m} \leq \sqrt[m]{\frac{1}{a_{m+1}}+\cdots + \frac{1}{a_{n}}} \leq \sqrt[m]{\sum_{i=m + 1}^n\frac{1}{2^{i!}}}$. And $\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{2^{i!}} \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-m-1} \frac{1}{2^{m! m}} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{m!(1+k)}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{m!m}}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^{m!m}}.$ Taking mth roots yields $\sqrt[m]{\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{2^{i!}}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{m!}}.$ So $a_m \ge 2^{m!}$.

Comment: Can this help, it seems strongly related ? https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h37427p234089

Comment: @zwim thanks. In that proof, isn't $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{r_i} \ge \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{a_i}$ by the inductive hypothesis? And if so, how can one then conclude that $a_n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{r_i}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{r_i})(a_k-a_{k+1})<a_n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{a_i})(a_k-a_{k+1})$?